# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fullmatch'

Tags: python-3.x

I imported re, the regular expression library. However, calling `re.fullmatch()` results in this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fullmatch'.
```

`re.match()` works though. I have made sure that I do not have a re.py file, and I am running on python version 3.7.3

any suggested fixes?

Comment: Is there something like re.fullmatch? Do you have a link to refer?

Comment: Are you really sure you're running Python 3.7.3? You may have installed multiple versions. The error message seems to be from an older version, and `fullmatch` only exists since version 3.4. If you start `python` on the command line, which version is printed on the first line?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved: I was using pytest, and turns out it was using python version 2, even though I was running on python version 3. I needed to reinstall pytest using pip3 install pytest

Answer (score 1):

please refer this doc - https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch

also, please check wether your python version supports re.fullmatch or not.

execute the below commands

```
import re
dir(re)
```